# Line break in edge labels in tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking

I'm using `tikz` and `pgf` to draw state machines in a document, and I'd like to be able to have a multiline edge label between two nodes. Something like the following would be ideal:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm,auto]
    \node[state] (one) {$q_1$};
    \node[state] (two) [right of=one] {$q_2$};
    \path[->] (one) edge node {$line1 \\ line2$} (two);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, the typesetting of that fails with the message "There's no line here to end." (Adding additional mathmode markers before and after the line break changes the error message to the vaguer "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.")

Is there a way to break the label in this graph into two lines?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't think you can break math lines like that.  But you can break text lines if you specify an alignment for the text in the node:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm,auto]
    \node[state] (one) {$q_1$};
    \node[state] (two) [right of=one] {$q_2$};
    \path[->] (one) edge node[align=center] {$line1$\\$line2$} (two);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

(You need an up-to-date version of tikz for this.)

Comment: It worked for me too, thanks. Just a side note: if you don't specify `...[align=center]` (or left, or right) it doesn't work (at least in my case)

Comment: Indeed, `align=center` seems to be required